# use perl to extract specific output lines

Tags: perl, sed, prolog, nlp, output

I'm endeavoring to create a system to generalize rules from input text. I'm using [reVerb](https://github.com/knowitall/reverb) to create my initial set of rules. Using the following command[*], for instance: 
`$ echo "Bananas are an excellent source of potassium." | ./reverb -q | tr '\t' '\n' | cat -n`

To generate output of the form:

```
    1  stdin
    2  1
    3  Bananas
    4  are an excellent source of
    5  potassium
    6  0
    7  1
    8  1
    9  6
   10  6
   11  7
   12  0.9999999997341693
   13  Bananas are an excellent source of potassium .
   14  NNS VBP DT JJ NN IN NN .
   15  B-NP B-VP B-NP I-NP I-NP I-NP I-NP O
   16  bananas
   17  be source of
   18  potassium
```

I'm currently piping the output to a file, which includes the preceding white space and numbers as depicted above.

What I'm really after is just the simple rule at the end, i.e. lines 16, 17 & 18. I've been trying to create a script to extract just that component and put it to a new file in the form of a Prolog clause, i.e. `be source of(banans, potassium).`

Is that feasible? Can Prolog rules contain white space like that?

I think I'm locked into getting all that output from reVerb so, what would be the best way to extract the desirable component? With a Perl script? Or maybe sed?

*Later I plan to replace this with a larger input file as opposed to just single sentences.

Comment: should be possible in perl, but `sed`, (I love it), forget it, life is too short. `awk` will be easier to get up to speed with, but `perl` has a much larger 'tool-box'  There may already be a package that deals with the problem, (I don't know).. So trade off, get stuff done pretty quickly in awk, but if things get an order of mag more complicated, then you'll have to start the higher learning curve or perl. As is, your details make it hard to guess the normal range of size for reverb files created. 7 wds input = 18 lines, How many lines for 100 wds of input? How many lines to process? Good Lk!

Comment: @shelter I guess the last three lines of the output will always be the rule, do you know how I can use perl to grab the meat off those lines and put it into that prolog form? I'm quite new to perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems wasteful. Why not leave the tabs as they are, and use:

```
$ echo "Bananas are an excellent source of potassium." \
  | ./reverb -q | cut --fields=16,17,18
```

And yes, you can have rules like this in Prolog. See the [answer by @mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081531/use-perl-to-extract-specific-output-lines/28083942#28083942). You need to know a bit of Prolog before you move on, I guess.

It is easier, however, to just make the string a a valid name for a predicate:

- `be_source_of` with underscores instead of spaces
- or `'be source of'` with spaces, and enclosed in single quotes.

You can use probably `awk` to do what you want with the three fields. See for example the `printf` command in `awk`. Or, you can parse it again from Prolog directly. Both are beyond the scope of your current question, I feel.

Comment: is there a way to insert some kind of delimiter in between all of those columns, i.e. a ' , ' or soemthing? maybe | cut --fields= 16 | echo ',' | cut --fields=17 | echo ',' | cut --fields = 18 >> output.txt

Comment: ^ that doesn't work. I tried to use the parameter --delimiter=, but that also didn't work

Comment: tabs are sort of hard to work with though, i mean conceptually and also practically because there is whitespace in some of the outputs

Comment: @user3787253 Keep in mind that the delimiter you chose depends on the possible contents of the fields you are delimiting. For example, if a field can contain commas, you can't use a comma for the delimiter. Tabs are the default delimiters for most command line tools. You can always convert them to something else if you prefer so, using for example `tr` like you did originally. You need to know what your final goal is.

Comment: my final goal is to have a bunch of clauses like contains(<food>,<nutrients>) and then make a system that can infer rules it hasn't seen before based on those variables, so like, contains(vitamin c, oranges) and prevents(scurvy, vitamin c) the system could tell you that prevents(scurvy, oranges)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69379/discussion-between-user3787253-and-boris).

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 'N;N
:cycle
$!{N
   D
   b cycle
   }
s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 (\1,\3)/p' YourFile
```

if number are in output and not jsut for the reference, change last sed action by
`s/\^ *[0-9]\{1,\} \{1,\}\(.*\)\n *[0-9]\{1,\} \{1,\}\(.*\)\n *[0-9]\{1,\} \{1,\}\(.*\)/\2 (\1,\3)/p`

assuming the last 3 lines are the source of your "rules"

Comment: thank you for that. please forgive me for my ignorance, but I've tried to run this command but it generated the error
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command

Comment: maybe I can run it as a bash script?

Comment: not needed, you are using certainly a GNU sed and i write a posix version so add `--posix` as parameter (just after `sed`) and `-e ` (with the space) before the first `'`

Comment: I tried it as

sed --posix -n -e 'N;N :cycle $!{N D b cycle } s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 (\1,\3)/p' YourFile

but still the same error. so your saying i can run it as a command?

Comment: YourFile in this case is the content of your line in a file, but you could pipe it at the end of your line (without `yourFile`in this case)

Comment: i was thinking i could run the command that i specified in the original question and then maybe pipe it to this sed operation and then pipe that to an output file that would just have the information from those three lines, is that possible? it's sort of freaking me out that the operation you first wrote is spread out over so many lines, could it all be condensed into one line that can go as a command line operation?

Comment: no probleme for piping and reduce to one-liner. In GNU sed (not standard posix), replace new line by a `;`  (like this `sed -n 'N;N;:cycle;$ ...'). Another way is to put the  sed code in a file and reference the file with `-f`like this `| sed -n -f FileWithAction`

Comment: no GNU sed environment here but with my aix it works (not the one liners version due to posix limitation on label)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Prolog part of the question:

Yes, Prolog facts can contain whitespace like this, with suitable operator declarations present.

For example:

```
:- op(700, fx, be).
:- op(650, fx, source).
:- op(600, fx, of).
```

Example query and its result, to let you see the shape of terms that are created with this syntax:

```
?- write_canonical(be source of(a, b)).
be(source(of(a,b))).
```

Therefore, with these operator declarations, a fact like:

```
be source of(a, b).
```

is exactly the same as stating:

```
be(source(of(a,b)).
```

Depending on use cases and other definitions, it may even be an advantage to create this kind of facts (i.e., facts of the form `be/1` instead of `source_of/2`). If this is the only kind of facts you need, you can simply write:

```
source_of(a, b).
```

This creates no redundant wrappers and is easier to use.

Or, as Boris suggested, you can use single quotes as in `'be source of'/2`.